# Two continuous function $f,g : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ with $\max_{x\in [0,1]} f = \max_{x\in [0,1]} g$. Prove $\exists c \in [0,1]$ s.t $f(c)=g(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

Suppose there are two continuous function $f,g : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ with $\displaystyle\max_{x\in [0,1]} f = \max_{x\in [0,1]} g$. Prove that there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$.

**My attempt:** First of all, since $f,g$ are defined on compact set with continuity so they can achieve them max/min i.e this is well-defined.

I have a feeling to prove this thing using Intermediate Value Theorem. I can directly say if $f$ and $g$ gets positive and negative values then from Bolzano Theorem $\exists c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$ but we don't know something like this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider $f(x)-g(x)$.  Show it is ${}\ge 0$ at some point and it is ${}\le 0$ at some point.  Conclude it is $0$ somewhere between.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769044/42969

Comment: I fixed mistakes in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769050/732945). Once my edit is approved, that link will contain a full answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that there exist $x_{0}\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769044/show-that-there-exist-x-0-in0-1-such-that-fx-0-gx-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u \in [0, 1]$ be a point s.t. $f(u) = \max f$, and similarly $v = \arg \max g$. Proceed by cases.

If $u = v$, we are done, i.e., $c = u = v$ is the desired point s.t. $f(c) = g(c)$.

Otherwise if $u \neq v$, then consider $h: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Note that at the desired point $c$, we have $h(c) = f(c) - g(c) = 0$. Therefore, it suffices to show that $\exists c \in [0, 1]$ s.t. $h(c) = 0$. Consider $x = u$. Since $f$ achieves its maximum at $u$ and $\max f = \max g$, we have $h(u) = f(u) - g(u) \geq 0$. Similarly, at $x = v, h(v) \leq 0$. Then by the intermediate value theorem, $\exists c \in [0, 1]$ s.t. $h(c) = 0$, as desired.